# Laravel PHP Fileinfo extension must be installed/enabled to use Intervention Image

Tags: laravel

I have enabled this extension in php.ini by un commenting also restarted the xammp but it is still not working. I need image intervention for resizing the image. I am using Laravel 5

Comment: Are you sure you are editing the correct `php.ini` file? Check that by simply creating a page with `<?php phpinfo();?>` it should give the information you need to find the right config file.

Comment: Yes, I have edited the right php.ini file but it is still showing this error.